# Video not playing in LibreOffice Impress

Tags: 18.04, libreoffice, mp4

Using Ubuntu 18.04.4 and LibreOffice Impress 6.0.7.3

When I insert an mp4 video in the slide only a screenshot of the video appears and I am not able to play it. How do I play mp4 videos in LibreOffice Impress presentations?

Answer (score 4):

I have not found a solution for mp4 video. But as described in [this article](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/smb-technologist/embed-video-into-a-libreoffice-impress-presentation/) LibreOffice support Ogg Vorbis video format. After the conversion of mp4 video to ogg format and subsequent insertion the converted video files seem to be working.

To convert mp4 to ogg I used FFmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
       -c:v libtheora -qscale:v 6 -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 \
       output.ogv
```

Comment: Perhaps the following would produce a better quality  video stream though: `ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libtheora -qscale:v 6 -c:a libvorbis -qscale:a 5 output.ogv`

Comment: @andrew.46 Yes, your proposal produces a better quality video with smaller size. Thank you!

Comment: You could add this to your answer then, substituting for the original syntax you have given. This should make your answer stronger. If you are unsure how to do this I can do it for you :)

Comment: @andrew.46 You can do that because it is your solution ;)

Comment: This wasn't enough for me.  I needed to install Gstreamer (which is what LibreOffice uses to play the videos), through the command line using the information at: https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-linux.html

Answer (score 0):

On another site I found this suggestion - before starting to run the presentation with F5, select the slide which has the video and then press F5. The presentation will still start from the first slide, but will play the video correctly - audio & video - when it comes up.

After working successfully in Linux Mint 20.2 for some time I had to use a Windows 10 machine for a presentation. Started normally I had the no-video problem, selecting the video slide before hitting F5 worked for me. It not only played the selected slide OK,but also two others which were later in the sequence - not in successive slides BTW.

Comment: So it works on W10? How is it related to Ubuntu?