# How to run mp4 videos in Impress

Tags: libreoffice, mp4

I have to insert mp4 videos in an Impress slideshow in Ubuntu 22.04, but I'm not able to reproduce it during the presentation. I can only see a a black image (if I click on the space where the video should be, it goes to next slide).

Meanwhile I converted those videos to AVI format. The problem now is clicking on running video it stops itself (pause), but on the second click instead to restart playing it goes to next slide, so the pause/play effect on that video does not work.

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: ubuntu 22.04 64 bit. Meanwhile I converted those videos to AVI format. The problem now is clicking on running video it stops itself (pause) but on the second click, instead to restart playing, it goes to next slide, so the pause/play effect on that video does not work

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1456175/edit) and put all the things in your comments, in the question.

Comment: Duplicate question with a different solution (which worked for me, while the answer here didn't work for me): https://askubuntu.com/a/1267208/326100

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and install gstreamer.

Run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-tools gstreamer1.0-x gstreamer1.0-alsa gstreamer1.0-gl gstreamer1.0-gtk3 gstreamer1.0-qt5 gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio
```

Open Impress and try inserting it again with 'Insert>Audio or Video'.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: The problem now is clicking on running video it stops itself (pause) but on the second click, instead to restart playing, it goes to next slide, so the pause/play effect on that video does not work